# Removing leading zeros from column in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

how to remove leading zero from this

```
number        RESULT WOULD BE LIKE THIS
00000.9         .9
A0001.1         A1.1
G0101.3         G101.3
00808.8         808.8
J0000.5         J.5
```

Comment: The first line seems to be leading `O` (letter `O` as in office) - not zeroes.....

Comment: Please ask your question clear.

Comment: Where are the leading zeroes?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @input varchar(10);
declare @output varchar(10);
set @input = '00000.9';
while ((ISNUMERIC(substring(@input,1,1)) = 0)  or (substring(@input,1,1) = '0'))   
  begin
    if substring(@input,1,1) = '0'
      begin
      set @input = substring(@input,2,len(@input) )
      end
    else
      if  ISNUMERIC(substring(@input,1,1)) = 0
        begin
          set @output = substring(@input,1,1); 
          set @input = substring(@input,2,len(@input))
        end

end
  if LEN(@output) > 0 
    set @input =  @output + @input
select @input
```

@input is your input

Comment: HOW CAN MAKE EDITION IN BELOW FUNCTION SO THAT IT WORK  LIKE UR FUNCTION

Comment: Create function functionname (@input varchar(10)) returns   varchar(10)) begin my sql so far return @input end

Comment: ya that i know but i write the below function i want customize change in that only

Comment: set @input = '00000.9'; there you can type whatever you want.

Comment: is your topic question answered?

Comment: please advice I want customize change that the number 0000.9 converts to 0.9

Comment: So why don't mark my answer as the right one? For your question add a if substring(@input,1,1) ='.' Set @input = '0'+@input before the

Comment: Select @input. Sorry had a bug posting the first comment

Answer (score 0):

ALTER FUNCTION NUMBER(@NUMBER VARCHAR(7))

RETURNS VARCHAR(7)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @NUM VARCHAR(1)

DECLARE @NUM1 VARCHAR(7)

SET @NUM= SUBSTRING(@NUMBER,1,1)

IF(@NUM LIKE '[A-Z%]')

```
   BEGIN
       SET @NUM1=@NUM+''+CAST(CONVERT(FLOAT,SUBSTRING(@NUMBER,2,7),2)AS VARCHAR(7))
   END
```

ELSE

```
  BEGIN
       SET @NUM1=LTRIM(STR(cast(@NUMBER as float),case when len(cast(@NUMBER as float))          > 7 then 7 else len(cast(@NUMBER as float)) end,1))
  END
```

RETURN @NUM
END